# Has "fud" made it into mainstream Spanish as a word for "food?"

Tags: préstamo-lingüístico

Twenty years ago, I learned the use of "fud" as a word for "food" in Mexican Spanish. In that context, it referred to a certain type of canned "fud" or perhaps in Spanish, "fud de latas."

Is "fud" used as a word for food, or "alimentos" outside of northern Mexico? And would it refer to "food" generally, or only certain types of foods?

Comment: Could it be referring to the brand [FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FUD_(brand))?  They do a lot of canned meats.  I've never heard the term (nor heard of the brand) before.

Comment: @guifa: That may be it.

Comment: I'm thinking of "spam", which is also a brand of canned meat.

Comment: As far as I know, fud is just a brand name as @guifa mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, you are right on spot @Envite , it's customary to buy canned meat if going camping, and FUD is a popular brand to buy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. *I was born here*, I've also lived in and traveled to many places all around México.

I can tell you for sure I've never heard someone refer to food as "fud" in spanish. My guess about what "fud de latas" meant would be that it had something to do with this industrial brand of food products named "[FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FUD_%28brand%29)", it is very popular because the company spends heavily on TV advertising and the products are decent enough.

I hope this answer cleared your doubt.

Answer (score 6):

Never heard it in Spain, not even in a passing manner,  so I'd say: No, at least not in Spain